# Is there another way to compute $ \lim_{x \to 0^+} (\ln x)/{x^{1/9} } $?

Tags: calculus, limits

Im trying to compute the limit

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{ \ln x}{x^{1/9} } $$

Im trying l'hospitals it doesnt work. What trick do we need here?

Comment: The logarithm approaches negative infinity, while the the exponent denominator approaches 0. Both the top and bottom must approach infinity or 0, not one or the other.

Comment: Why do you presume the limit is computable?  i.e. why do you think the limit converges.  L'hopital yields  $\lim -1/9x^{19/9} = - \infty$.  That *does* work.

Comment: LHR will work on the reciprocal.  That is, $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^{1/9}}{\log(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\frac19 x^{-8/9}}{1/x}=0$.  For $0<x<1$, $\log(x)<0$.  Therefore, the limit of interest must be $-\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the substitution $x=y^9$, where $y>0$.

Comment: Rene, how does this help here?  Is $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\log(x)}{x}$ somehow conceptually easier to evaluate than the limit of interest?  -Mark

Comment: @Mark In my opinion, yes.

Comment: Rene, and why do you believe that?

Answer (score 11):

One may just write
$$
 \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{ \ln x}{x^{1/9} } = \lim_{x \to 0^+}\left( \frac1{x^{1/9} } \times   \ln x \right)=\frac1{0^+} \times (-\infty)=+\infty \times (-\infty)=-\infty.
$$

Answer (score 10):

It is not an indeterminate form: it is: ‘ $\dfrac{-\infty}{0^+}=-\infty\times(+\infty)=-\infty$’.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/623503)

Comment: I'm sorry. For me it *is* an answer, since the O.P. asks whether there is another way than L'Hospital. Furthermore, if it's not indeterminate, 1) one cannot apply L'Hospital; 2) the answer is trivial.

Comment: Bernard, LHR applies to cases $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ for which each $f$ and $g$ is differentiable in a deleted neighborhood of $c$ and $|g|\to \infty$.  BUT, the limit of $f$ does not need to diverge to $\infty$.  In fact, $\lim f$ need not even exist.  [See the "Note" here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_proof).  So, one does not need an indeterminate form in such a case.  And note that the limit of the reciprocal is indeed of an applicable, non-indeterminate form.  ;-))  - Mark

Comment: @Bernard Ok....perfect. You can delete all your comment. I delete mine.

Answer (score 4):

Without appealing to L'Hospital's Rule, we note that $\log(x)\le x-1$ for $x>0$.

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\log(x)}{x^{1/9}}&\le \frac{x-1}{x^{1/9}}\\\\
&=x^{8/9}-x^{-1/9}\\\\
&\to -\infty \,\,\text{as}\,\,x\to 0^+
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

---

It is interesting to note that L'Hospital's Rule does indeed apply to the limit of the reciprocal, $\frac{x^{1/9}}{\log(x)}$. That is,

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x^{1/9}}{\log(x)}&=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\frac19 x^{−8/9}}{1/x}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac19 x^{1/9}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Now, since for $0<x<1$, $\log(x)<0$, we immediately see that

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\log(x)}{x^{1/9}}=-\infty$$

Comment: Why was this "down voted?"  Would the down voter care to state why??

Comment: Perhaps because you didn't justify that inequality? I guess...